# Querying an Excel spreadsheet and returning results? But which program?

Tags: python, excel, batch-file

A company I am working for has recently asked the head tech to compile a spreadsheet that has every single computer name listed, along with the person that uses that computer. The idea is that Help Desk can have this spreadsheet open, so when the user calls, they can find their name and therefor their associated computer number.

However, this seems a bit clunky to me. We have around 1000 users, so that spreadsheet would just be a pain imho. I thought it might be easier to have a simple program that asks you for the User's name, you type it in, and it returns the computer number.

So, I am assuming this program would reference this spreadsheet and then return your information. Of course, it doesn't have to reference the spreadsheet, it could reference something else.

I am only experienced with Python, and only because I took a Introductory class on it for college. However, I am thinking a Batch file would work better? Or would something else work better? I am taking this as a chance to learn and perhaps offer a neat utility to our Help Desk, and was just looking for advice. :)

Thank you.

Comment: A simple vlookup on a worksheet in the Excel file could do this.

Comment: @TimWilliams or Ctrl+F, heh. But I still think from a UI perspective, there's nothing too wrong about doing it through python. It can be neater for some people (me included) to run a simple search through a console command than open up a goddamn excel file every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning on using python with the excel, there's two (most common, there are others) ways to go:

1. use the windows API, which lets you run native excel commands through python. i.e.:

   ```
   from win32com.client import Dispatch
   excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
   excel.Visible = True #if you want to see it
   sheet = excel.Workbooks.open('Book1').Sheets('Sheet1')
   # get value from a cell:
   sheet.Cells(1, 1).value

   # get range
   sheet.Range('A1:A2000')

   # etc. google about vlookup and other functionalities. You can run anything you would in excel through python here, it's just an API
   ```

   this will be the fastest most efficient method, as it uses native excel functionalities and those are optimized. On the other hand, it's not very user-friendly, as the windows API is kinda messy (that's my opinion at least).
2. Now if you're like me, and prefer to go pythonic, you can use the excellent [xlrd library](http://www.python-excel.org/) which is very easy to use

   ```
   import xlrd
   book = xlrd.open_workbooks('Book1')
   sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
   sheel.col(1)
   ```

   I'm not gonna delve any deeper. You'll have to figure it out yourself, and as you can see, it ain't too hard. Also, note that if you'd like to also *write to the file* you'll need another library called xlwt.

Of course, there's also a third option - pass the data to a proper database (SQLite will probably suffice) and use SQL queries to fetch the data. That would be the most fast and efficient way to go, if that's important to you (SQL *was* created for this exact purpose, unlike excel. so uh... y'know).

Good luck!

Comment: 4th option: export the file as CSV and just work with the raw data.

Comment: @l4mpi: Working with CSV is not appreciably easier than with Excel and the `xlrd` package. In fact, for arbitrary cell access (instead of row-by-row access), `xlrd` is actually the easier way.

Comment: @yuvi: Actually, `win32com` is notoriously slow. It's true that *Excel* is fast, but there is some overhead required to launch it and communicate with it. Depending on the task, it can be quicker to just read the file directly with `xlrd`.

Comment: @yuvi: Passing the data into a database would be **by far** the slowest and least efficient way, if the data is going to be maintained in Excel and have to be loaded into the database each time you want to do a query on it. If you mean the database will be kept in sync automatically somehow, then *maybe* it would be quicker. Maybe. This is a fairly small amount of data (OP said about 1000 rows) to resort to a database if it's not already in the database.

Comment: @JohnY OP says it's about a thousand rows of data, even if each line has 10kb of data (which seems highly unlikely) this should be loaded in way below a second with a DictReader. On the contrary, using an excel library can be slow and potentially has a lot of overhead if the file is in OpenDocument format - I've had java (Apache POI) choke on a 2MB xlsx file, consuming >512MB RAM (the file did have 30*10k cells though). But the amount of data OP actually needs, which is 1000 names each mapped to a number, should only occupy a few KB anyways, so I doubt performance is a concern here.

Comment: @l4mpi: Have you actually *used* `xlrd` or are you just guessing? It's true that reading a CSV is typically faster than reading an Excel file, but to export to CSV either requires human intervention... or **reading the Excel file first anyway**.

Comment: @JohnY I have not used xlrd but similar libraries like Apache POI, as stated in the previous comment; but it's obvious that a badly designed zipped xml format will have a massive overhead compared to an ascii file. And of course converting the file to CSV requires human intervention, but unless the source file is changing often (of which there is no indication) you only have to do it once, and **writing the program requires human intervention anyway**.

Comment: @l4mpi: Even if the data never changes, your proposal is to convert to CSV, and write a program. I'm saying you can skip the conversion step, and just write a program. And if the data *does* change, then your proposal requires further conversion.

Comment: @JohnY when I said "use a proper db" I meant it should *replace* the excel file. As for win32com - maybe opening the file is slower, but I think querying on the data using native functions will still be faster than xlrd.